# Abstract Django model manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaprogramming

I lack Python metaprogramming knowledge here. Let's say I have the following:

```
class OwnCompanyManager(models.Manager):
    """Only companies of this user"""
    def get_queryset(self, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return super(OwnCompanyManager, self).get_queryset()
        return super(OwnCompanyManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            companyuser__user=user)


class OwnPublisherManager(models.Manager):
    """Only publishers of this user's company"""
    def get_queryset(self, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return super(OwnPublisherManager, self).get_queryset()
        return super(OwnPublisherManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            company__companyuser__user=user)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    objects = models.Manager()
    own = OwnCompanyManager()


class Publisher(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    allow_latest_dev = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    domains_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = models.Manager()
    own = OwnPublisherManager()
```

I have many more than that. I dislike the copy-paste boilerplate `Own(Publisher|Company|Etcetra)Manager)`. The only change is, as you can see, in the filter.

How can I abstract `Own(InsertModelNameHere)Manager` and use it from `Company`, `Publisher` and other models? I would like to specify the filter kwargs in manager definition.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for metaprogramming or anything particularly clever here. You just need to extract the bits that change. In this case, it's just the arguments to `filter`: you can use the dictionary form of argument passing, and store the filter as a string in a class attribute.

```
class AbstractManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return super(AbstractManager, self).get_queryset()
        return super(AbstractManager, self).get_queryset().filter(**{self.filter: user})

class OwnCompanyManager(AbstractManager):
    filter = "companyuser__user"

class OwnPublisherManager(AbstractManager):
    filter = "company__companyuser__user"
```

Comment: This looks better. However, would it be possible to have AbstractManager and no other classes? I.e. construct the Manager class in the model definition?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Daniel's reply:

```
class OwnManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, key):
        super(OwnManager, self).__init__()
        self.k = key

    def get_queryset(self, user):
        if user.is_superuser:
            return super(OwnManager, self).get_queryset()
        return super(OwnManager, self).get_queryset().filter(**{self.k: user})


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    objects = models.Manager()
    own = OwnManager("companyuser__user")


class Publisher(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    allow_latest_dev = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    domains_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = models.Manager()
    own = OwnManager("company__companyuser__user")
```

That way I don't want to create stupid class for every model.

Thanks Daniel.